# how to call simple wcf from fiddler

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple wcf soap service. Running it in visual studio and it's running on localhost

[image]

Trying to access the GetData method from fiddler but it gives Bad request 400. What am I doing wrong?

```
http://localhost:23150/Service1.svc/GetData?value=1
```

GET

Service:

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

```
[OperationContract]
string GetData(int value);

[OperationContract]
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

// TODO: Add your service operations here
```

}

```
  public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
```

Comment: Have you exposed your WCF service as RESTful service? eg - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/590627/Converting-SOAP-based-WCF-Service-to-RESTful-Desig

Comment: use `SOAP UI` instead.

Comment: I never know we can invoke web service using fiddler :O.where have you implemented GetData? post the code

Comment: Added GEtData code also

Comment: i dont see any issue here, do you have a way to see your code? probably a team viewer or something?

Comment: As your operation responds to soap requests, you should use SOAP UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to design your [OperationContract] like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetData")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetData?value={value}")]
```

Now run your service and from fiddler, choose the GET verb and send request. I'm sure it will work now.